# How to set private file directory of Drupal by Bitnami on AWS ECS Fargate?

Tags: drupal, containers, amazon-ecs, bitnami, aws-fargate

Drupal 9 requires that the private file directory be set by editing the Drupal settings.php file. However, when I deploy the Drupal by Bitnami container (https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/drupal/) on AWS ECS Fargate, I am unable to SSH in to the machine and update the settings.php file.

I'm aware that one solution may be to configure ECS Exec (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/new-using-amazon-ecs-exec-access-your-containers-fargate-ec2/) so that I can tunnel into the container and edit the settings.php file. I'm wondering if that's the ideal solution, or if there is some way to use Docker/ECS commands to potentially:

1. Copy a custom settings.php file from an outside source (local, or S3)
   or
2. Append text to the settings.php file this container creates after site installation
   or
3. Something I'm not considering

The ultimate goal would be to set a private file directory which I can mount to an EFS system to. So, if there's an EFS related shortcut I'm missing here, that could also prove useful.

I tried looking through the Drupal by Bitnami documentation to see if there was an environment variable or parameter I could set for the private file directory, but I did not see anything.

Thanks in advance,
Jordan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to modify the settings after the container is running is the **wrong** way to do something like this. That method doesn't scale, and doesn't work in any sort of automated/fault-tolerant/highly-available environment. You shouldn't think of a running docker container as a server that you can then modify after the fact.

If you absolutely want to change the volume path in settings.php then you probably need to create custom docker image, using this Bitnami image as the base, and as part of the Dockerfile for that custom docker image you would either copy a new `settings.php` file in, or modify the existing file.

However, I'm confused why you need to edit `settings.php` to change the path. The [documentation for the image you are using](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/drupal/) clearly states that you need to create a persistent volume that is mapped to the `/bitnami/drupal` path. There's no need to change that to anything else, just configure your ECS Fargate task definition to map an EFS volume into the container at `/bitnami/drupal`.

Comment: Thanks Mark, that is helpful. I want to edit the settings.php because this container does not set a default private file directory, only a public file directory. I'm concerned that, even if I were to mount an EFS volume onto /bitnami/drupal, that would only be used to serve public website files.

Comment: Then you'll have to modify the docker image to create your own custom version before deploying it to ECS.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll follow your advice and create a custom docker image which copies a settings.php file from S3 and places it into my container. 

I assume the container will need the AWS CLI installed so I believe the nature of my question is shifting. I'll mark this as resolved and purse:

"How to copy a file from S3 into ECS Fargate container"

Comment: Why do you need the file to be in S3? Look into how the `COPY` command works in a `Dockerfile`

Comment: I see that COPY needs a source and a destination. I was thinking that S3 would be the easiest source path for Fargate to COPY from. I suppose another option would be to mount the EFS volume onto /bitnami/drupal and copy it from there? But that would require me placing my settings.php into the Drupal public file directory which seems unwise.

Comment: Fargate doesn't create custom docker images. It runs your pre-build docker image. The COPY command in a `Dockerfile` is a build time command, not a run time command. You would be building the docker image on your local computer (unless you are doing something like a CI/CD system), pushing it to ECR, and then having Fargate run the image. At build time, the settings.php file would need to be on your local computer, where you are building the image.

Comment: Ah, that's exactly the distinction I was missing!